# Php add multiple data with jquery and store mysql with json

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

Hi I have a small e commerce application.
I want when click plus button add new td and post all data with array
I want store this size with json in my product table

[product screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fpQSt.png)

My table details like this;

```
 CREATE TABLE `products` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `title` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `sizes` longtext CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_bin NOT NULL CHECK (json_valid(`sizes`)),
  `created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp()
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

how can I do that? my code;

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header">Add Product</div>
                <div class="card-body">
                    <form action="<?=baseURL?>/add.php" method="POST">
                      <div class="mb-3">
                        <label for="title" class="form-label">Title</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="title" name="title" required>
                      </div>
                      
                      <div class="mb-3">
                        <table class="table">
                          <thead>
                            <tr>
                              <th scope="col">Size</th>
                              <th scope="col"></th>
                            </tr>
                          </thead>
                          <tbody>
                            <tr>
                              <td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="size" placeholder="42" name="size"></td>
                              <td><a class="btn btn-sm btn-success" id="addSize" name="addSize">+</td>
                            </tr>
                          </tbody>
                        </table>
                      </div>
                      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">Add</button>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Jquery script

```
<script>
        $( document ).ready(function() {
            $( "#addSize" ).click(function() {
              
            });
        });
    </script>
```

And its my php code

```
$title  = $_POST['title'];

$sizes  = json_encode($_POST['sizes']);

$stmt = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO products (title,sizes) VALUES (?, ?)");
$stmt->execute(array($title,$sizes));
$stmt = null;

header('location:'.baseURL);
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Hello check this [link](http://jsfiddle.net/QmHdL/) to see how to add a row onclick

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title>Table Example</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function addField (argument) {
            var myTable = document.getElementById("myTable");
            var currentIndex = myTable.rows.length;
            var currentRow = myTable.insertRow(-1);

            var linksBox = document.createElement("input");
            linksBox.setAttribute("name", "links" + currentIndex);

            var keywordsBox = document.createElement("input");
            keywordsBox.setAttribute("name", "keywords" + currentIndex);

            var violationsBox = document.createElement("input");
            violationsBox.setAttribute("name", "violationtype" + currentIndex);

            var addRowBox = document.createElement("input");
            addRowBox.setAttribute("type", "button");
            addRowBox.setAttribute("value", "Add another line");
            addRowBox.setAttribute("onclick", "addField();");
            addRowBox.setAttribute("class", "button");

            var currentCell = currentRow.insertCell(-1);
            currentCell.appendChild(linksBox);

            currentCell = currentRow.insertCell(-1);
            currentCell.appendChild(keywordsBox);

            currentCell = currentRow.insertCell(-1);
            currentCell.appendChild(violationsBox);

            currentCell = currentRow.insertCell(-1);
            currentCell.appendChild(addRowBox);
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <table id="myTable">
        <tr>
            <td><input type="text" name="links"></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="keywords"></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="violationtype"></td>
            <td><input type="button" class="button" value="Add another line" onclick="addField();"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML FORM

```
<form>
    <div class="mb-3">
      <label for="title" class="form-label">Title</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="title" name="title" required>
    </div>
    <div class="mb-3">
        <label for="title" class="form-label">Size</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="size" name="size" required>
    </div>
    
    <div class="mb-3">
      <table class="table">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th scope="col">Title</th>
            <th scope="col">Size</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">Add</button>
</form>
```

JS

```
<script>
    $( document ).ready(function() {
       $('form>button').click(function() {
           var form = document.querySelector('form');
           var elements = form.querySelectorAll('input[type="text"]');
           let data = [];
           elements.forEach((element) => { data[element.name] = element.value});
           add_to_tbl(data);
           post(data);
        });
     });
     function post(data){
         data = Object.assign({}, data)
         $.post('/*To PHP file or url*/',data, (res)=>{
                    console.log(res);
         });
      };
      function add_to_tbl(arr) {
          let tr = $('<tr/>');
          for (const key in arr) {
              if (Object.hasOwnProperty.call(arr, key)) {
                  tr.append($('<td/>').text(arr[key]));
               }
           }
           $('.table').find('tbody').append(tr); //change id to your table id
        };
 </script>
```

PHP file

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST)){
    $title  = $_POST['title'];
    $sizes  = json_encode($_POST['size']);
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO products (title,sizes) VALUES (?, ?)");
    $stmt->execute(array($title,$sizes));
    if($stmt){
        echo json_encode(['status'=>'200']);
    }else{
        echo json_encode(['status'=>'400']);
    }

}else{
    echo json_encode(['status'=>'404']);
}
?>
```

```js
$('form>button').click(() => {
            var form = document.querySelector('form');
            var elements = form.querySelectorAll('input[type="text"]');
            let data = [];
            elements.forEach((element) => {
                data[element.name] = element.value;
            });
            add_list(data);
            // post(data);
        });

        function add_list(arr) {
            let tr = $('<tr/>');
            for (const key in arr) {
                if (Object.hasOwnProperty.call(arr, key)) {
                    tr.append($('<td/>').text(arr[key]));
                }
            }
            $('.table').find('tbody').append(tr);
        };
        function post(data){
            let url = '';
            data = Object.assign({}, data)
            $.post(url,data, (res)=>{
            });
        };
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header">Add Product</div>
                <div class="card-body">
<form>
        <div class="mb-3">
          <label for="title" class="form-label">Title</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="title" name="title" required>
        </div>
        <div class="mb-3">
            <label for="title" class="form-label">Size</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="size" name="size" required>
        </div>
        
        <div class="mb-3">
          <table class="table">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th scope="col">Title</th>
                <th scope="col">Size</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">Add</button>
      </form></div></div></div></div></div></div>
```